# Fixing the PHP empty function

Tags: php, function, object

PHP has the habit of evaluating (int)0 and (string)"0" as empty when using the `empty()` function. This can have unintended results if you expect numerical or string values of 0. How can I "fix" it to only return true to empty objects, arrays, strings, etc?

Comment: Personally, I think (int)0 should evaluate as false; it's just (string)"0" that shouldn't.  Also, note that empty objects don't count as `empty()`, and the accepted answer doesn't change this.

Comment: @Brilliand - given php's overall design, that ints and numeric strings are interchangeable, that probably wouldn't be a good change.

Comment: ... IMHO It would be simpler if `empty` was false for values that are equivalent to 0. Then it often would be useful as-is; we wouldn't need workarounds like this Q&A.  In the cases where one wanted to include 0-equivalents, would simply do `if (empty($var) || $var == 0)`.  Ah well.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This didn't work for me.

```
if (empty($variable) && '0' != $variable) {
  // Do something
}
```

I used instead:

```
if (empty($variable) && strlen($variable) == 0) {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: The first one fails because you use `!=` instead of `!==`.  `(empty($variable) && $variable !== '0')` would actually be a nice and concise way to test this.

Comment: @thomasrutter - hopefully your code will never encounter `" 0"` or `"00"` or `"-0"`. Those won't be detected by `!== '0'`, but do have contents. A good example of why one should write code that says your intent, instead of being clever.

Answer (score 19):

I seldom use `empty()` for the reason you describe.  It confuses legitimate values with emptiness.  Maybe it's because I do a lot of work in SQL, but I prefer to use `NULL` to denote the absence of a value.

PHP has a function `is_null()` which tests for a variable or expression being `NULL`.

```
$foo = 0;
if (is_null($foo)) print "integer 0 is null!\n"; 
else print "integer 0 foo is not null!\n";

$foo = "0";
if (is_null($foo)) print "string '0' is null!\n"; 
else print "string '0' is not null!\n";

$foo = "";
if (is_null($foo)) print "string '' is null!\n"; 
else print "string '' is not null!\n";

$foo = false;
if (is_null($foo)) print "boolean false is null!\n"; 
else print "boolean false is not null!\n";
```

You can also use the exactly equals operator `===` to do a similar test:

```
if ($foo === null) print "foo is null!\n";
```

This is true if `$foo` is `NULL`, but not if it's `false`, zero, `""`, etc.

Comment: `isset` would be a more appropriate replacement than `is_null`.  If the OP chose `empty` over a simple (likely implicit) cast to boolean, then I would assume that it's possible for the variable to be undefined.

Comment: I wouldn't use `is_null` unless of course you are wanting `$foo = ""` to be treated as NOT NULL.

Comment: @Brett, Right, in PHP and in SQL, a string with zero length is not the same as a null. Oracle database assumes `""` is the same as NULL, but that's nonstandard.

Comment: @BillKarwin Yes I agree, but my point was more in relation to this question as it seems they would not want an empty string to be treated as valid content, but if you used `is_null` it would be.

Answer (score 8):

"0" is [always considered false](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) (or empty) in PHP, and it does make alot of sense (not that I'll argue that here). If you want to have zero evaluate to true as well, use `strlen($value)`.

Comment: Good advice, although you'll probably want to throw a trim() around $value.

Comment: and in the same time empty('false") return false

Answer (score 7):

I always add to my codebase

```
function is_blank($value) {
    return empty($value) && !is_numeric($value);
}
```

and use it instead of empty(). It solves the issue of keeping zeros (int, float or string) as non-empty.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#103756 which was added May 2011.

Comment: great solution, I named it `is_nothing()` instead of `is_blank`, but that's just me.

Answer (score 4):

"Fixing" is one point of view. Another would be to assume it's not "broken", and learn to work with it the way it was intentionally designed.

Given the problem as you describe it, the best thing would be to tighten up your code so the variable can't be put into an indeterminate type state. Otherwise, you'll want to test for datatype using gettype().

Comment: From what I understand it is now recommended that one use is_x rather than the older gettype() function.

Comment: The problem is the OP appears to want a type-independent solution. With PHP, the complete enumeration of is_? options may change. It's far better to avoid the train wreck in the first place.  Actually, what they probably want is points for an abstract question. :)

Comment: +1 for the points fishing comment. It does seem like the OP was a little quick with their own solution to a non-existent problem. Still, if you want a type independent solution I would use "===" operator instead.

Comment: Right, and even then a type-independent solution is a bad thing to want in the first place.

Comment: I have a reaction opposite to @NoahGoodrich. -1 for fixating on the word "fixing", rather than responding to the key sentence *"This can have unintended results if you expect numerical or string values of 0"*. This is a very common issue when using php - not fixed by "tightening your code".

Comment: In what universe is the string "0" to be considered empty?

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking you want to use the triple equals operator to determine when a value truly is null or false. This is more specific and the results **ALWAYS** return exactly as expected.

Creating a separate function to do something that you can do in a single line of code but using a different operator seems to be overly complicated and adds additional obfuscation.

Additionally, many programmers tend to use 0 or an empty string to denote a non-existent value but it is more correct (and I feel a better practice) to use a null value to denote any value (regardless of type) that is truly non-existent.

Comment: The real problem with it IMHO is that it discards precision and abets sloppy thinking.

Comment: In SQL as Bill pointed out, NULL is a non-existent value and an empty string is an empty string. I like to check for NULL's explicitly as well as invalid strings and integers depending on the needs of the program.

Comment: In other words, sometimes a zero or empty string is valid but these should be tested independent of a test for null values

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use `empty()` for something it's not intended for. Personally, I think it's behaviour comes from an older programming paradigm in PHP and it could probably be retired.

Instead, make your checks more explicit. Rather than checking if the value is not useful, check that it is. For example, if you want an array, check it's an array (`is_array()`) rather than checking whether it's a string.

Also, you can rely on the fact that all `$_POST` and `$_GET` variables are strings, so you can make comparisons to "", or check that `strlen() == 0`.

Comment: Sometimes $_POST or $_GET variables are arrays.

Comment: sometimes $_POST or $_GET will not have the key, meaning value of `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

I use this to detect emptiness:

```
''  --> true
'0' --> false
0   --> false
```

the function:

```
function is_empty_or_zero($str) {
 return (is_null($str) || ($str === ''));
}
```

Comment: `is_empty_or_zero` isn't a good name for this function. `is_null_or_empty_string` is what you are testing. Specifically, "zero" returns *false*. Maybe you meant `is_empty_but_not_zero` as the name; though that's not as good as saying your intent directly. Another approach is to define the *opposite* (negation) of this function, and call it `has_contents`. `if (!has_contents(...))` is quite readable, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I created an `IsEmpty()` a terse quick function.

```
function IsEmpty($mData) {
    return is_int($mData) ? false : 
        is_string($mData) ? $mData=="" : 
        empty($mData);
}
```

Comment: Answering your own question before seeing any other responses? -- Your solution conflates everything into one complex statement, effectively obfuscating it (not considered good style in most places).

Comment: @le dorfier: there's no problems with answering your own questions: it's just creating more information for others to read and learn by.
@null: one of the key benefits of using empty() is that you can test undefined variables without causing a warning. this function doesn't have this same ability.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( is_int($val) || !empty($val) ) {;}
```

Comment: What advantage is there to this approach, over using `is_numeric`, as in Stemar's answer?

Answer (score 0):

I used [`ord`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) function to check either the value passed was empty or not.

```
/*
* SPACE is not empty - Please do trim before using this function for your own purpose
*  var_dump(is_having_value(0));        // true
   var_dump(is_having_value(0000));     // true
   var_dump(is_having_value("    0"));  // true
   var_dump(is_having_value(""));       // false
   var_dump(is_having_value("  "));     // true
   var_dump(is_having_value('\t'));     // true
   var_dump(is_having_value(''));       // false
   var_dump(is_having_value('o'));      // true
   var_dump(is_having_value('O'));      // true
   var_dump(is_having_value('0'));      //true
   var_dump(is_having_value(null));     //false
   var_dump(is_having_value());         //false
*/
function is_having_value($val = null) {
    if (is_array($val) || is_object($val)):
        $logic_empty = empty($val);
        return !$logic_empty;
    else:
        $ascii = ord($val);
        if ($ascii == 48 || $ascii = 0 || $ascii == 32):
            return true;
        else:
            $logic_empty = empty($val);
            return !$logic_empty;
        endif;
    endif;
}
```

Comment: What advantage is there to this approach, over using `is_numeric`, as in Stemar's answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want an equivalent to `empty($var)` which returns false when var is the string "0", you can use:

```
if (($var ?? 0) != '')
```

The reason this works is:

- `$var ?? 0` is a shortcut for the ternery `isset($var) ? $var : 0`.  That is, if  the variable on the left doesn't exist it takes the value on the right, without issuing a warning or notice, as with isset() or empty().
- `<value> != ''` does an implicit cast of the empty string when the left value isn't a string.  This returns false for any false-like value of `<value>` such as null, false or (numeric) 0.  However, for the string "0", this will return true, since no cast will be performed and `"0" != ""` is true.

Answer (score -3):

The most effective solution for this problem is to test if the variable is false e.g.

```
if (!$variable_name) {echo $variable_name;}
```

It doesn't matter if the variable is empty or null, it all equals to false when put in a if conditional.

Comment: that's pretty much the same as empty(), in that 0 or "0" will be false, which is what the OP was trying to avoid.

Comment: also throws a strict notice if the variable is not set

Comment: It's also slightly more obfuscated over empty(). I'd advise against this, unless the variables is only true or false.