# PHP: what's an alternative to empty(), where string "0" is not treated as empty?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fixing the PHP empty function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410002/fixing-the-php-empty-function)

In PHP, empty() is a great shortcut because it allows you to check whether a variable is defined AND not empty at the same time.

What would you use when you don't want "0" (as a string) to be considered empty, but you still want false, null, 0 and "" treated as empty?

That is, I'm just wondering if you have your own shortcut for this:

```
if (isset($myvariable) && $myvariable != "") ;// do something
if (isset($othervar  ) && $othervar   != "") ;// do something
if (isset($anothervar) && $anothervar != "") ;// do something
// and so on, and so on
```

I don't think I can define a helper function for this, since the variable could be undefined (and therefore couldn't be passed as parameter).

Comment: I think I now realise that there is no solution to this - at least not one that can make this code any shorter.

Comment: Found solution: `if (($var ?? 0) != '')`.  The `$var ?? 0` is a shorthand for `isset($var) ? $var : 0`.  Then the `!= ''` does an implicit cast to string.  If the value is null, false, or numeric 0 then it is false, but if it's string "0" it is true as there is no cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is that it isn't possible to shorten what I already have.

Suppressing notices or warnings is not something I want to have to do, so I will always need to check if empty() or isset() before checking the value, and you can't check if something is empty() or isset() within a function.

Answer (score 33):

This should do what you want:

```
function notempty($var) {
    return ($var==="0"||$var);
}
```

Edit: I guess tables only work in the preview, not in actual answer submissions. So please refer to the [PHP type comparison tables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) for more info.

```
notempty("")       : false
notempty(null)     : false
notempty(undefined): false
notempty(array())  : false
notempty(false)    : false
notempty(true)     : true
notempty(1)        : true
notempty(0)        : false
notempty(-1)       : true
notempty("1")      : true
notempty("0")      : true
notempty("php")    : true
```

Basically, notempty() is the same as !empty() for all values except for "0", for which it returns **true**.

---

Edit: If you are using **error\_reporting(E\_ALL)**, you will not be able to pass an undefined variable to custom functions by value. And as mercator points out, you should _always_ use **E\_ALL** to conform to best practices. [This link](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/03/24/10-useful-php-tips-revisited/) (comment #11) he provides discusses why you shouldn't use any form of error suppression for performance and maintainability/debugging reasons.

**See orlandu63's answer for how to have arguments passed to a custom function [by reference](http://us.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).**

Comment: That will fail when the variable is undefined.

Comment: How do you mean? If passed an undefined variable, the function returns false--which is the opposite of what empty() returns: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php That is the desired behavior.

Comment: It does not fail, but produces a warning. So, although it does work, it is not The Right Way(tm). You should use isset() before checking the variable with ===

Comment: Strange, it doesn't produce any warnings when I have error reporting set to E_STRICT. If does however produce an error when I use E_ALL. But then using isset() inside of the function does not prevent the error either.

Comment: It seems that you can't pass an undefined variable to a custom function in E_ALL regardless of whether your use isset() or not. Gushiken's implementation without a custom function does work in all circumstances however.

Comment: E_STRICT isn't a superset of E_ALL: http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php. You should use (E_ALL | E_STRICT). You *could* use the @ operator, but that adds overhead (see http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/03/24/10 "tip" #9 and comment #11) and isn't The Right Way™ either.

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work for me because it will fail (ie produce PHP notice) when the variable is undefined.  I rely on PHP notices.  I hadn't realised, I guess, that it's not possible to define a function that can accept an undefined variable; empty() and isset() are magical in that way.

Answer (score 10):

```
function isempty(&$var) {
    return empty($var) || $var === '0';
}
```

The key is the `&` operator, which passes the variable by [reference](http://us.php.net/references), creating it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Clever thinking, wouldn't this still issue an error (or warning, or notice) if $var doesn't exist?

Comment: Actually, this function silently causes an undefined variable to become defined (as null), without issuing an error or notice of any kind.

Comment: your function will return true for "0".

Answer (score 8):

```
if(isset($var) && ($var === '0' || !empty($var)))
{
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if ((isset($var) && $var === "0") || !empty($var))
{

}
```

This way you will enter the if-construct if the variable is set AND is "0", OR the variable is set AND not = null ("0",null,false)

Comment: This looks quite correct; it isn't really a shortcut for if (isset($myvariable) && $myvariable != "") though as it's longer.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Void($var)
{
    if (empty($var) === true)
    {
        if (($var === 0) || ($var === '0'))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This has the problem that if $var is undefined, it fails as soon as it's passed as an argument (to a function other than isset or empty, such as your Void function).  I think what I was wanting is actually impossible, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If ($var != null)

Comment: This will error if $var is undefined.